# LWC Quick Action - Submit for Approval

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, quickaction

I am attempting to create a Quick Action using an LWC to submit a Quote for Approval. I had this done in APEX and Visualforce however I want to convert it to LWC. I found that in order to use Quick Action for an LWC I need to use @api invoke() however I am not sure how you can use the invoke and call a Apex Class.

What Ideally I want to happen is to have Validations Messages display on the Screen. If No Validation the display Approval Submitted.

HTML

```
<template>
<div class="toast toast_hide" style="height:4rem" data-id="toast">
    <div class="slds-notify_container slds-is-relative">
        <div class={notifyClasses} role="status">
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">error</span>
            <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} alternative-text={type}></lightning-icon>
            <div class="slds-notify__content">
                <h2>{title}</h2>
                <p>{message}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-notify__close">
                <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:close" alternative-text="Close"></lightning-button-icon>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript
I am not sure how to include @API invoke here. I keep getting a syntax error.

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import someMethod from '@salesforce/apex/clsSubmitToOrderLWC.ValidateQuoteForApproval';


export default class lwvSubmitToOrder extends LightningElement {
@api invoke() {
    //Call Method that returns the Message if something is not filled out. 
    //Else Return Submitted
    @wire(someMethod, {idProduct:'$recordId' })

    callSomeMethod({error, data}) {
        if (data) {
            // process results
        } else if (error) {
// this.template.query() seems not valid for LWC use this.template.querySelector as below            
//this.template.query('c-toast').show(error.message || error.body.message, 'error');
this.template.querySelector('c-toast').show(error.message || error.body.message, 'error');

        }
    }
}
}
```

APEX

```
public with sharing class clsSubmitToOrderLWC {

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static SBQQ__Quote__c soQuote(Id idQuote) {
    
    return [Select Id, SBQQ__LineItemCount__c, Order_Entry_Admin__c, RecordType.DeveloperName
    From SBQQ__Quote__c 
         Where Id = : idQuote];

}


@AuraEnabled
public static String ValidateQuoteForApproval(SBQQ__Quote__c soQuote) {
boolean blnError = False;
String strErrorMessage = '';
  
    If(soQuote.RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Official_Sales_Quote'){
        soQuote.Sales_Order__c = True;
    }

    If(soQuote.SBQQ__LineItemCount__c == 0){
       strErrorMessage = strErrorMessage +  'Wait a Second! This Particular Quote has no Quote Line items' + '<br>';
       blnError = True;    

    }
    If(soQuote.Order_Entry_Admin__c == null){
       strErrorMessage = strErrorMessage +  'This Quote does not have Order Entry Admin Selected! ' + '<br>';
       blnError = True;    

    }

    If(blnError == True){
          Return strErrorMessage;
    }Else{
        Update soQuote;
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        req1.setComments('');
        req1.setObjectId(soQuote.id);
        Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
              
        strErrorMessage = 'No Validation Message Submitted for Approval';
        Return strErrorMessage;  
    }
}
}
```

Comment: is this a screen action or just an action? invoke is only available for headless actions (no screen). What is the syntax error message you receive?

Comment: Yes I want a headless action like this: https://www.forcetrails.com/2021/05/lightning-web-component-headless-quick-action.html - the outcome is to display strErrorMessage on Screen

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out..

You cant use @API Invoke and @Wire together.

```
@api invoke() {
@wire(someMethod, {idProduct:'$recordId' })
```

you have to write it like this:

```
@api invoke() {

someMethod, {idProduct:'$recordId' })
```